# Which Platform Best Suite Software Development C#.net,WPF,MFC

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mfc

I am new to Software Development, could you please give me some input into which platform is mostly used by other Software Developers.

I am looking to develop software which has DB Connectivity with an attractive customisable UI. 
Please recommend the what is currently used in the IT industry by other Successful Software Developers.

Comment: Why have you Title Cased every single word? This question has too many answers, why not try again giving an example of the product you're trying to make and asking if there is a language suitable for it? Narrow things down a bit for us.

Comment: There is no real consensus regarding the "best" development platform, never has been and probably never will be. Development platforms are so different and suit different things, so it is extremely unlikely that there will ever be a consensus on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simply best development platform. If so every developer should be developing with that instead of using many different tools and platforms. Every platform has its pros and cons. Personally I would recommend you c#. Its easy to start with. Its development environment(visual studio) is very good for interface design(especially for windows forms development) and its very good to start learning object oriented approach, which is very important in software development. If you can clarify you needs more maybe I can recommend something else. 
There are many web development tools if you want to develop a web application. Dreamviewer is more simpler than visual studio to start designing web applications.

Answer (score 4):

If you are really new to learning try to read few books on C#, WPF, MFC and play with it. Choose the one which is more fun to work with and that will drive you to learn a lot. If you are into Industry then mostly your project needs drive you towards a particular choice.

But as i mentioned if you want to be successful learn one which is fun to you.